# How do write a unit test suite with Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js

I've seen a ton of links out there trying to explain, but what I'm looking for is a how-to set up my test harness and unit tests. So far I have an HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>EmberJS Testing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="scripts/bower_components/qunit/qunit/qunit.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bower_components/qunit/qunit/qunit.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="scripts/bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="scripts/bower_components/ember/ember.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I'm not sure how to further incorporate tests into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a quick example of qunit into the [ember.js wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ember.js/info)

Here's the example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wipo/3/edit